# Mostrar contenido en mi body, con JS

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, web

lo que me gustaria hacer, es que en mi index.html, en la parte del body se carge toda la pagina, digamos le pico a "contactos" del nav, y me carge el contenido de un archivo contactos.html, dentro de el body.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <script src="js\main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <button id="Inicio" name="Inicio">Inico</button>
        <button id="Contactos" name="Contactos">Contactos</button>
    </nav>

    <body id="Cuerpo">
        <!-- aqui quiero que me cargue todo al presionar algún button del divsi presiono en el button contacto, me cargue contactos.html, si le doy a inicio me cargue inicio.html, y muestre el contenido dentro del body -->
    </body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de una carpeta de tu ordenador crea un archivo de texto `contenido.txt`y otro `index.html`

En el index.html pon esto:

```html
<div id="Cuerpo">
    <!-- aqui quiero que me carge todo al precionar algun botton del div -->
</div>

<script>

function leerFichero(fichero)
{
    var miContenido = new XMLHttpRequest();
    miContenido.open("GET", fichero, false);
    miContenido.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(miContenido.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(miContenido.status === 200 || miContenido.status == 0)
            {
                var miTexto = miContenido.responseText;
                Cuerpo.innerHTML = miTexto;
            }
        }
    }
    miContenido.send(null);
}

leerFichero('contenido.txt');

</script>
```

En el `contenido.txt` pon esto:

```
<h1>TEST</h1><p>Alguna cosa m&aacute;s</p>
```

Al abrir el `index.html` tendrías que ver el encabezado y el párrafo. Naturalmente puedes llamar la función `leerFichero` al hacer click en algún botón.

Espero que esto sea útil

Comment: Me marca error en la función, no me abre el archivo u.u

Comment: Abre esto: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/cfda78f587ebe39902c470e719cfd7e3